# How to support multiple screen sizes for iPhone in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, autolayout

How can we support multiple screen sizes in Xcode iOS for iPhone? Why isn't it any kind of guide for this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use constraints.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html